# How to make countdown start every eight hours?

Tags: javascript

I wonder how to make countdown start every 8 hours? for example 
the puzzle starts at 10 pm next is 6 am, and next 2 pm.

I have javascript like this

```html
<script>
    var countDownDate = new Date("May 31 2020 22:00:00");
    var now = new Date();

    if (now.getHours() < countDownDate.getHours()) {
        countDownDate = countDownDate;
    } else 
    if (countDownDate.getHours() <= now.getHours()) {
        countDownDate.setDate(countDownDate.getDate() + 1);
    }

    var x = setInterval(function() {

        var now = new Date();

        var distance = countDownDate - now;

        // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);



        // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " +
          minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

        // If the count down is over, write some text and start new countdown
        if (distance < 0) {
          clearInterval(x);
        }
      }, 1000);



</script>
```

and how to make that countDown date every 8 hours? like 10 pm, 6 am and 2 pm? Thank you.

Comment: The date is hard-coded?

Comment: yeah its by default. but i just htinking about how to make countdown star every 8 hours

Comment: Make the date dynamic?

Comment: yeah realtime countdown not static

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours Setting the hours might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about wrapping it in a function that takes in a date (in ms, in this case) (`countdown(date)`) and then calling the function with 8+ hours once the timer is up:

```
    // Set the date we're counting down to
    var countDownDate = new Date("May 31, 2020 22:00:00").getTime();

function countdown(date) {
    // Update the count down every 1 second
    var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get today's date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now and the count down date
    var distance = date - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);



    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
    + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

    // If the count down is over, write some text and start new countdown
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
        let newDate = date + (8 * 3600 * 1000);
        countdown(newDate);
    }
    }, 1000);
}

countdown(countDownDate);
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/h3t54vkq/) using initial countdown set to 3 seconds from now.

Code Explanation:

1. take in the initial date - can be set to anything.
2. Countdown until the initial date is reached.
3. Start a new 8-hour timer.

Example case starting date = "May 31, 2020 19:37:35".

1. First countdown will countdown 5 hours (from now to 19:37:35).
2. Second countdown will countdown 8 hours (from 19:37:35 until
   03:37:35).
3. Third countdown will countdown 8 hours (from 3:37:35 to 11:37:35).

Comment: for example = 10:00 PM War Start in 02:43:42, 06:00 AM War Start in 10:43:22, 02:00 PM War Start in 18:43:10 , how to make like that bro. i jsut wondering i cant jsut edit date because the date is always change but you keep reffering to 6 am, 2 pm, 10 pm

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to be able to set the initial date/time, and have the subsequent timers adapt to that. That's what this code does. There is no 6 am, 2 pm and 10 pm hardcoded. You can change the initial countDownDate to "May 31, 2020 02:43:42" and it will work. Try testing it.

Comment: but how about next day ? i shoukld change the countDownDate too ?

Comment: It updates the date automatically via "let newDate = date + (8 * 3600 * 1000)". The initial countDownDate is just to define the first countdown - after that one expires, it will run a new timer for a date that is 8 hours from the present moment.

Comment: yeah but it set to expired, and how to make it back to 23 hours again to reach 10 pm ? if i already at 10 pm ?

Comment: check this demo https://jsfiddle.net/h3t54vkq/ using initial countdown set to 3 seconds from now. This will show you what happens when the timer expires.

Comment: bro im glad to see you want to help me but that's not waht i mean,, 

if i at 10 pm now. it will countdown next to 23 hours to react 10 pm , and part 2 need 8 hours to react 6 am, and need 16 hours to reach 2 pm . thats  what i mean.

Comment: and will be daily countdown if we change day

Comment: That's exactly what the code I have given you does... https://jsfiddle.net/h3t54vkq/1/.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/h3t54vkq/2/ - example using Jun 1st as the starting date.

Comment: bro i already see ur link here https://jsfiddle.net/h3t54vkq/2/, bro thats no i mean.. you will countdown back if  now() = 10 pm and will countdown back and countdown date will be 23 hours to reach 10 pm . but if now() < 10 pm, countdown for 10 pm will be remaining at countdowndate - now() .

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not understand you. You'll have to articulate your problem more clearly if you need more help. Perhaps try recreating your problem in one of the demos.

Comment: yeah thank you for suggestion and time to help me eheh. i just confusing of this problem hahah

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215026/discussion-between-damjan-ostrelic-and-alexsandro-siregar).

Comment: Let me try explaining the code one more time:
1. take in the initial date - can be set to anything.
2. Countdown until initial date is reached.
3. Start new 8 hour timer.

Example case starting date = "May 31, 2020 19:37:35".
First countdown will countdown 5 hours (from now to 19:37:35).
Second countdown will countdown 8 hours (from 19:37:35 until 03:37:35).
Third countdown will countdown 8 hours (from 3:37:35 to 11:37:35).

Comment: broo can u check my code script that was i update a sec ago ?

Comment: i alrady fixe bro with some if function  and of course with ur help too. thankss for help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to evaluate the starting countdown time by current time, then set the start of countdown time to that time.

Something like:

```
var countDownDate = new Date("May 31, 2020 22:00:00");
var currentHour = countDownDate.getHours();
// 10 pm to 6 am
if(currentHour >= 22 && currentHour < 6) { 
    // set countdown startTime to 10 pm 
    countDownDate.setHours(22);
}
// 6 am to 2 pm
else if(currentHour >= 6 && currentHour < 14) {
    // set countdown startTime to 6 am 
    countDownDate.setHours(6);
} else {
    // set countdown startTime to 2 pm 
    countDownDate.setHours(14);
}
```

Comment: nahh, i think the same as you think, but the problem is how to change Date ("May 31, bla bla bla) to our current date and hours now but we keep reffering to 10 pm, 6 am, 2 pm ? for example if my currentdate is May 31 2020 7 pm , but i should reffering to 10 pm, and if my cur date is 31 may 2020 4 pm need 6 hours to 10 pm

Comment: That means you need to know the next [10pm, 6am, 2pm], not the previous [10pm, 6am, 2pm]. Right? 
In my codeblocks it detects the previous [10pm, 6am, 2pm].

Comment: noo..

i have a assumption

e.g if my war start only at 6 am, 2 pm, 10 pm, and my question how to countdown reffering to that

Comment: for example = 10:00 PM War Start in 02:43:42, 06:00 AM War Start in 10:43:22, 02:00 PM War Start in 18:43:10